# Running a command in term from eshell with arguments

Tags: eshell, term

Basically I want to run `watch` from `eshell`.

Simply running `watch date` (for example) doesn't work (only the first header line is displayed).  Apparently I should run it with `term` or `ansi-term` but these two commands take only one argument -the command, which would be `watch` - and I don't know where to put the arguments (i.e. `date` in the example above).

So, I guess my question is: What is the proper way to run `watch date` (or any other `watch` such as `watch "make myprog && ./myprog"`) from `eshell`?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. I found a non-trivial answer. Looking at functions `term` and `ansi-term`, I saw that though they themselves only take one program-related argument, under the hood they both invoke functions that allow passing additional arguments to programs (`make-term` and `term-ansi-make-term` respectively). This gave me an idea about how to accomplish what you want:

- for `term`: `(switch-to-buffer (make-term "test-term" "/bin/bash" nil "-c" "watch date"))`
- for `ansi-term`: `(switch-to-buffer (term-ansi-make-term "test-ansi" "/bin/bash" nil "-c" "watch date"))`

It's a bit unwieldy in that form, so you might want to write a function abstracting this:

```
(defun eshell/watch-process (process)
     (switch-to-buffer
      (term-ansi-make-term "test-ansi" "/bin/bash"
                   nil "-c" (format "watch %s" process))))
```

And then you can run `watch-process date` directly in Eshell.

Answer (score 2):

The Eshell documentation refers to commands that are not line-oriented but are designed to run in a terminal, such as `watch`, as "visual commands".  To tell Eshell that a command is a visual command, add its name to the list in the `eshell-visual-commands` variable as follows:

```el
(push "watch" eshell-visual-commands)
```

Thenceforth Eshell will automatically run `watch` in a `term` buffer.

See [Input/Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Input_002fOutput.html) in the Eshell manual.